# http post request to host with https url in C language returns HTTP 302

Tags: c, http

i have program in c in which i am trying to post data through http request  with host having url as https then in response HTTP 302 status of redirection is coming always, but for host with url on  http (just for checking)it doesn't show redirection related status.

Comment: This looks more like a statement than a question...

Comment: That's normal behaviour, so you should write code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and HTTPS may have absolutely different behaviour, they may lead to different content, they are even run on different TCP ports (80 and 443 by default). So, you should not compare HTTP and HTTPS. Also it is very common when http redirects you to https (it's not your case, but it might be something else like that).
So, just implement redirection.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. but in response the url for redirection coming is same as what i m using as host url to connect to server. Like go.urbanairship.com i am using as host  and in response also it shows                                          Location: https://go.urbanairship.com   for redirection...

Comment: may be protocol has changed ? from https to http. or path on the server has changed...